# White line in flexbox item that wont go away

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

[image]

So my problem is that i cannot figure out how to get rid of this white line in the image. Please can someone at least tell me why this is happening. I have tried to get rid of it but I've had no success. Ive tried inspecting the element and there is no border there. Its seriously frustrating.
Here is the html for this element (it is a flex item).

```
 <div class="section-packages-flex">

  <div class="section-packages-item">
    <div class="section-packages-image">
      <h3 class="package-heading"><span class="package-underline">Package 1</span> <br /><span class="orange">The Zebra</span></h3>
      <img class="img-responsive" alt="Package 1 - The Zebra Package" src="_images/package-2.png">
    </div>
    <div class="section-packages-content">
      <div class="section-package-content-full">

      </div>
      <div class="section-package-content-split">

      </div>
      <div class="section-package-content-split">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section-packages-pricing orange-background">
      <h3>R 2500.00</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the css.
Background

```
.orange-background {
    background: rgba(245,123,32,1.00);
    background-color: rgba(245,123,32,1.00);
}
```

Parent Container:

```
.section-packages-flex {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between; 
}

.section-packages-item {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
}

.section-packages-pricing {
    width: 20%;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(88,88,88,0.00);
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(88,88,88,1.00);  
}
```

Comment: To get your answer, It is better to create a **code snippet** or a **fiddle**, So we can inspect as you did.

Comment: I can't see any white line with your code, is it browser specific issue? If possible add working snippet.

Comment: I think it is the white vertical line 1px width, on the right side of orange div.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle or a codepen

Comment: Ok, so i made a pen but it does not show the white line. (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWewRz) it seems to only be happening on chrome not firefox

Comment: It might be better to view the website :s haha http://www.foxandfriendsparties.co.za/ under packages

Comment: On your website, not getting the white line in either Chrome or FF. No issue here.

Comment: Damn, its strange i see it on all the pc here at my work. Ok thanx for looking though. I appreciate it. I will post the solution if i find it.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually a bug in Chromium based browsers. I tried it on Firefox, and it works perfectly fine. Hope they fix it soon.

This is why I hate CSS lol. They should implement a standard user agent :/

Answer (score -1):

I just added a negative margin value to get rid of it.

Comment: Bad idea. Using negative margins to "hide" problems only causes problems in the future. Best to find out what actually causes the problem in the first place!